# Extract month name from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having Ruby on Rails application. In application on one of the place I am calling API which returning me the string as `Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov`. My requirement is when I show this on user interface I need to show it as `Up 4.35% from October to November`.

Can someone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Will the string format always have the months as in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date::MONTHNAMES` may be able to help you.  If they are always 3-character shortened versions of the months, you could build a hash to help:

```
dates = Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.map { |m| [m[0..2], m] }.to_h
```

Then use it elsewhere:

```
text = 'Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov'
text.gsub(/#{dates.keys.join('|')}/, dates)
=> "Up 4.35% from October to November"
```

Comment: Good idea with Date::MONTHNAMES, but I would combine it with @toro2k's comment to MikDiet's answer for a better solution.

Comment: Indeed.  Updated to use those.

Comment: Be *very* careful with `dates.keys.join('|')`.

Comment: What does "be very careful" mean with that?

Comment: Read my answer, where it's explained.

Comment: `Regexp.union` is nice, hadn't seen that before.  You emphasis seems to indicate some type of extreme risk I'm not really seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` for this.

Just extend my example for all months:

```
"Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov".gsub(/Oct|Nov/) do |s| 
  {'Oct' => 'October', 'Nov' => 'November'}[s]
end
# => "Up 4.35% from October to November"
```

Comment: You can pass the hash as the second argument of `gsub`, there is no need of the block: `'abc'.gsub(/a|b/, 'a' => 'x', 'b' => 'y') # => "xyc"`.

Answer (score 1):

`String#sub` is what you need

Try this:

```
a = "Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov"
a.sub('Oct', 'October').sub('Nov', 'November') # you can continue with other months
#=> "Up 4.35% from October to November"
```

Answer (score 1):

People don't pay attention to this particular [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) ability, so meditate on this:

```
SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES = %w[
  January
  February
  March
  April
  May
  June
  July
  August
  September
  October
  November
  December
].map{ |m| [m[0, 3], m] }.to_h
# => {"Jan"=>"January", "Feb"=>"February", "Mar"=>"March", "Apr"=>"April", "May"=>"May", "Jun"=>"June", "Jul"=>"July", "Aug"=>"August", "Sep"=>"September", "Oct"=>"October", "Nov"=>"November", "Dec"=>"December"}

SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES_REGEX = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES.keys).source })\b/
# => /\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\b/

str = 'Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov'

str.gsub(SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES_REGEX, SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES)
# => "Up 4.35% from October to November"
```

Stripping out the output results in a very concise way to do rapid search and replace in a document:

```
SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES = %w[
  January
  February
  March
  April
  May
  June
  July
  August
  September
  October
  November
  December
].map{ |m| [m[0, 3], m] }.to_h

SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES_REGEX = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES.keys).source })\b/

str = 'Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov'

str.gsub(SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES_REGEX, SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES)
# => "Up 4.35% from October to November"
```

Older Rubies don't have `to_h` so you can use this instead:

```
SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES = Hash[%w[
  January
  February
  March
  April
  May
  June
  July
  August
  September
  October
  November
  December
].map{ |m| [m[0, 3], m] }]
# => {"Jan"=>"January", "Feb"=>"February", "Mar"=>"March", "Apr"=>"April", "May"=>"May", "Jun"=>"June", "Jul"=>"July", "Aug"=>"August", "Sep"=>"September", "Oct"=>"October", "Nov"=>"November", "Dec"=>"December"}
```

Breaking down the regex pattern generation:

```
SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES_REGEX = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(SHORT_TO_LONG_MONTH_NAMES.keys).source })\b/
```

- `\b` is a word-break or word-boundary, meaning where a word starts or ends. A "word" is the character-set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, AKA `\w`, and a word-break is the dividing line between the previous non-word character and the word-character. Failing to do that is the root of all sorts of human misery; Substrings will match without `\b` and you can get all sorts of interesting substitutions as a result.
- `(?:...)` defines a non-capturing group, which is a nice way to find an series of alternate patterns, which, in this case is the list of three-letter, shortened, month names.
- [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) is a useful method that takes an array, in this case, the keys of the hash, and separates them with a `|`, which is the OR symbol in patterns. Basically it means any of the keys can match.
- [`source`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html#method-i-source) is a very important part of this. Without it, the result of `Regexp.union`, which is a compiled regular expression, would be interpolated into the string, along with its associated flags which can cause conflicting searches. Consider the difference between these:

  ```
  /foo/i # => /foo/i
  /#{ /foo/i }/ # => /(?i-mx:foo)/
  /foo/i.source # => "foo"
  /#{ /foo/i.source }/ # => /foo/
  ```

  The first is a case-insensitive pattern. The second is a case-insensitive pattern embedded in a case-sensitive one, but the `(?i-mx:` flags it as insensitive internally. That's a bug in waiting unless you're really sure that's what you want.

  `source` returns the stringified version of the pattern without the flags, so the final result is what we'd actually expect.

I've been bitten by that before and it was a major pain to track down.

Finally, the Date class has some predefined constants, which would allow you to not have to define the hash in long-hand like I did above. That was to make it obvious what was happening, but for convenience you can do things like:

```
require 'date'

Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.zip(Date::MONTHNAMES)[1..-1].to_h # => {"Jan"=>"January", "Feb"=>"February", "Mar"=>"March", "Apr"=>"April", "May"=>"May", "Jun"=>"June", "Jul"=>"July", "Aug"=>"August", "Sep"=>"September", "Oct"=>"October", "Nov"=>"November", "Dec"=>"December"}
Hash[Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.zip(Date::MONTHNAMES)[1..-1]] # => {"Jan"=>"January", "Feb"=>"February", "Mar"=>"March", "Apr"=>"April", "May"=>"May", "Jun"=>"June", "Jul"=>"July", "Aug"=>"August", "Sep"=>"September", "Oct"=>"October", "Nov"=>"November", "Dec"=>"December"}

/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[1..-1]).source }\b)/ # => /\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec\b)/
```

Notice the use of `[1..-1]` in the samples. That's because the arrays contain a nil for their first value to make the arrays 1-based, not 0-based, for our lookup pleasure, but which can make Ruby howl if you're trying to use the arrays for patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(string)
    string.gsub("Jan", "January").gsub("Feb", "February").gsub("Mar", "March").gsub("Apr", "April").gsub("Jul", "July").gsub("Aug", "August").gsub("Sep", "September").gsub("Oct", "October").gsub("Nov", "November").gsub("Dec", "December")
end

str = "Up 4.35% from Oct to Nov"
```

and at the end, just call function:

```
replace(str)
```